# Jest VS Code extension not finding individual Tests but will run All Tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have a CRA application with Jest tests. I have installed the VS Code Jest Extension:

[image]

If I then click to Run all Tests, you can see that all tests complete 100% successfully:

[image]

However, if I then try to run an individual Test or Test Suite from here:

[image]

Jest UI reports that No Tests Were found then exits with a code 1:

[image]

It seems to find matches until it gets to the **testRegex** check. The location it is looking for seems to exist:

[image]

I cannot help but think that I have either not got a config setting correct or there is a bug with the Jest extension. I was wondering if anyone else has seen this behaviour and has overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was simply because I was using an older version of nodejs. I updated to the latest and it started working.

Comment: Which version of node did you update to?